# changing ng-model of the select from the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Given the following code of select:

```
<select ng-options="fieldType.value as fieldType.key for fieldType in fieldTypes" 
        ng-model="item"></select>
```

I'm trying to change the `ng-model` of the `select` from the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
    .controller('EditParamModal', function($scope){
         $scope.fieldTypes =  [
            {key: 'Text Box', value: 'textbox'},
            {key: 'Text Area', value: 'textarea'},
            {key: 'Dropdown List', value: 'select'},
            {key: 'Check Box', value: 'checkbox'}
        ];

        $scope.changeTheSelected = function(){
            item = 'textbox';
        }
});
```

I'm got an error, is there any way to do that? or it's not a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `item` to a reference of one of the object attributes in the `ng-options` array, as Angular uses object references for comparison.

Also, `item` is not something that exists on the global namespace (hopefully) so you need to reference it via `$scope`.

```
    $scope.changeTheSelected = function(){
        $scope.item = $scope.fieldTypes[0].value;
    }
```

See [Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3EdvKAQjewLMEsFbZXdW?p=preview)

Since you're binding to a String you can also do

```
    $scope.changeTheSelected = function(){
        $scope.item = 'textbox';
    }
```

Your original problem was missing the `$Scope` so you were setting a global variable called `item` and not actually changing the model.

See [Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/XhGETSuLHeOO4pcVqTOM?p=preview)

I would recommend the first approach though, it's a lot more robust.

Comment: No, If I did the following I put in item the following object: {key: 'Text Box', value: 'textbox'}, but I put in item just the value: 'textbox' ... this isn't good

Comment: Ah, my bad. It's `fieldType.value` in `ng-options`, I'll update my answer.